# How can I check that my GoogleSpreadsheet is in my drive or in a teamdrive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

Like I said on the title, I would like to run a Google apps script linked to a google spreadsheet only if the Spreadsheet is located on the user's drive because I work with Spreadsheet template located on teamdrive and the rule is that the user must make a copy on their local Drive to run the script. So I would like to know if it's possible with the file id for exemple to check if I am in a teamdrive or not ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `fileId` itself, you cannot know whether it is part of a shared drive or not.

However, you can use `DriveApp` to obtain the file itself, and most importantly, its [permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission.html). In order to check that the file is in a personal drive (and owned by the user issuing the request), you have to make sure the permission is in fact `OWNER`. You can do this with GAS as follows:

```js
function isInPersonalDrive(fileId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  return file.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()) === DriveApp.Permission.OWNER;
}
```